# Zig-zag array - solution

Tags: python, array

**The problem**

> For any given array, find a corresponding zig-zag array such the each
>   element (a,b,c,d,e...) follows the rule:
>
> ```
> a < b > c < d > e < f
> ```

In other words, every other element is greater than both of its neighbouring elements and the remaining elements are smaller than their neighbours.

For example, for the list:

```
[4, 3, 7, 8, 6, 2, 1]
```

the output is:

```
[1 8 2 7 3 6 4]
```

**My solution**

```
array = [4, 3, 7, 8, 6, 2, 1]
array.sort()

while len(array) > 1:
    print(array[0], array[-1], sep = " ", end= " ")
    array.pop(0)
    if array: array.pop(-1)
print(array[0])
```

Comment: (Hint: There is a cleaner solution utilizing [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip))

Comment: I'm not sure if you sure my update as I just changed it...

Comment: Actually on second thoughts, I'm wrong, but you're not supposed to update code. Updated code is supposed to be a new question as per the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry. As no one had replied I thought it'd be ok. I think you replied as I updated it

Comment: @Dair You can edit code before answers have been posted. There are some edge cases, but I don't think they're relevant here.

Comment: What output do you expect for `[1, 1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: What output do you expect for `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. I got this task from GeeksForGeeks and they didn't cover that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Python's slice notation. It allows you to pass steps, which allows you to do this with ease.

I also think it's fairly easy to understand.

```
def zigzag(values):
    half = len(values) // 2
    new = [None] * len(values)

    new[0::2] = values[:-half]
    new[1::2] = values[-half:][::-1]
    return new
```

```
>>> zigzag([1, 2, 3, 4])
[1, 4, 2, 3]
>>> zigzag([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: How come you have written [:-half]? What is with the minus sign? Thanks

Comment: I worked it out. I can see if I don't put the minus sign the sliced list is too short for lists of odd length if there is no minus sign

Comment: @EML It's short hand for `values[:len(values) - half]`. `values[-half:]` takes the last `half` amount of items. `values[:-half]` takes the first `len(values) - half` items - which is 2 in the first example and 3 in the second.